# Spring Boot server based on existing WSDL

Tags: java, spring-boot, wsdl

I'm developing a WSDL file and I want to create a server for testing with Spring Boot. As I want to have full control over the WSDL (Spring WS does some things I don't like), I want to write it myself and I would like to create a simple server to test the WSDL.

Is it possible to make Spring WS in the Spring Boot to use my static WSDL and expose it as it is? I don't want to use the dynamically generated WSDL for these reasons:

- The generated WSDL can't separate XSDs.
- There are some naming conventions for input and output elements of the operations that are not usable for my project
- As far as I know, the application must be run to create WSDL - it can't be generated during Maven build.

Also I want to use Spring Boot, so there should be one jar file, embedded Tomcat, not a war file.

Comment: How far can you get with `wsimport`?

Comment: `wsimport` is a tool for generating JAX-WS annotated classes. Spring WS uses it's own annotations, like @Endopint. Do I miss anything?

Comment: Post process the source code generated to get what you need